# How to save and restore sessions when using Capybara/Poltergeist for screen scraping

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, screen-scraping, poltergeist

I am using Capybara and Poltergeist for screen scraping.

I want to do something like the following, though I'm not sure if it's even possible, let alone how to bring at about.

```
class Sites < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :saved_session

  def do_thing_a_on_site
    current_session = Capybara.load_session(saved_session)
    do_thing_a
    update_attribute: saved_session, current_session
   end

  def do_thing_b_on_site
    current_session = Capybara.load_session(saved_session)
    do_thing_b
    update_attribute: saved_session, current_session
   end

end
```

Is this possible?

There are no `save`, `load` or similar methods in [Capybara::Session](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session).

Comment: What would you expect to be saved from the session?  The Capybara::Session is pretty much just a link to a browser - other than that it doesn't really have any state.

Comment: have worked out a system that saves and restores cookies and URLs -- when post when I'm satisfied it's doing all that I expect